# how to unmask the text in Ms Word?

Tags: ms-word

I don't want the light grey background for my text.I tried to copy the text from internet and paste it in Ms word the same background is still present. So please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste it as plain text, rather than just hitting CTRL-V.  You're maintaining the HTML style the way you're are doing it.

That is, right click, and choose the icon for "plain text only".  That will paste plain text and maintain your current style.

Comment: yup sir. Thank u so much. U have saved my time by helping with the suggestion.

Comment: Eggsellent.  You'll find that sort of trick works all across MS Office.  It's a good thing to know.

Comment: Sir i am troubling you. Plz don mind. can u suggest me how to make spacing between the lines inword

Comment: Highlight the text in question.  Right click and go to Paragraph.  All the settings, including line spacing, are in there.